# How does a browser require a .js file?

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, webserver

I'm developing a Web Server for android and I've some problems with external javascript files (.js).
With an external css it works fine, because it receives the TCP of the css file and then the server send it as a normal file.
with javascript files it doesn't receive any GET/POST request.

Can I include any tag to tell the browser to get a js file?

at this moment I only tried this one: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>`

**EDIT**:
I just added "text/javascript" content-type but nothing seems to has changed. If I open directly http://ip/js/javascript.js I get the text of javascript.js. Then, if I came back on my index.html, all javascript functions work... why?

**EDIT 2**:
My server (at this moment) doesn't use threads.. for each request it send the page and restarts the connection. this may be the problem??
but, in this case it should works "something"... no?

**EDIT 3**:
*I had a confirm that may be a thread problem:
if in html file I reverse the javascript and the CSS tag, javascript works, css doesn't work. What do you think?*

Comment: Make sure your server sends correct Mime type for JS files

Comment: What happens when you request the JS file directly from your server like: http://localhost/js/javascript.js ?

Comment: You must have this HTTP header `Content-Type: text/javascript` because you expect that type in `script` tag.

Comment: This should definitely make the browser attempt to `GET` the specified JS file. Use e.g. Firebug to see what happens when you request the main document in a desktop browser.

Comment: @Gustav Firebug tell me that a function doesn't exist. That's why it can't view the javascript file

Comment: @supergiox: I had Firebug's "Network" tab in mind - to see what the browser requests and gets, in its own opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you aren't caching the file on the client side.  If you have the js file linked in the page it will always attempt to download it, with the exception of caching.

Comment: I always clean the cache before trying. From the webserver I can see all requests.. I get a request for the page, for favicon.ico, for css, but no one for javascript.js

Comment: try changing the name of the js file in the html page and see if you receive anything on the server then.

Comment: I changed the name in index.html, but no news... My server (at this moment) doesn't use threads.. this may be the problem??

Comment: Ah threads! What server side technology are you using?  Have you looked at node.js? http://nodejs.org/

Comment: I've heard about node.js. But I'm writing this webserver in java, so I can use it on Android

Comment: The obvious answer is to implement threading - but in order for anyone to help you with that you're going to have to at least tell us how you're currently implementing this webserver

Comment: I found (but not yet resolved) the problem: `listenSocket.accept();`, where listenSocket is a ServerSocket. Without threads, when this method is called the server does some operation, but while it serves an http request (css file) it reiceive an other request (js file) and it ignore it. Now I'm writing the threaded version..  thanks for all suggestions!